# Origin of mistake when a Dutch says "You are true."

Tags: translation

Speaking English, Mark Rutte, the Dutch prime minister, mistakenly said `you are true` instead of `you are right`.

But where does the confusion comes from? 'You are right is' is 'je hebt gelijk' and 'True' and 'right' are quite different words in Dutch: 'waar', 'juist'

'gelijk' is a susbstantive, something that you have. Had he said 'you have right' the mistake would be clear to me.

What expression could interfere to lead him to the mistake?

Comment: Could even be internal English logic rather than Dutch interference. If a statement is right, that means the statement is true. But even if a person is right, they aren't true? What a country!

Comment: @LukeSawczak - If I am saying to someone, "you are right", it is almost invariably because they have made a statement that is correct. Idiomatically, one can also say of a statement, "that's right", which is equivalent to "that's true" - although in English, there are subtle differences of "tone" between the two. By analogy to _that's right_ -> _that's true_, one not entirely familiar with idiomatic English might well conclude that _you're right_ -> _you're true_ is a valid transformation.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin Yes, exactly.

Comment: I am almost sure Mark Rutte knows that it is not a correct sentence, it just came out of his mouth this way. Most likely he mixed up "you are right" and "it is true" but i don't think Dutch language plays a part in this confusion.